# At which player level are new gun levels unlocked?

Tags: mass-effect-andromeda

I currently have a crafted level III version of the deluxe edition gun and I could craft level IV, but since there is a bug preventing you from deconstructing DLC weapons (ie you lose the augments used during crafting), I'd prefer to skip level IV if level V unlocks soon.

Level V was not unlocked with player level 25 (which I had initially assumed since 1 gun level per 5 player levels would fit well) so I'm curious when it will unlock.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rank 5 unlocks at level 30.

Rank 6-10 unlocks every 10 levels past that.

If you go and try to research the weapons, you will see what the level requirements are for just about everything, the level requirements are standard across the board (this includes armor ranks).

The only piece of gear that seems to have no level requirements that I've found so far is the N7 chest piece.

Comment: and if my memory serves, I think rank 2 was unlocked at level 5, rank 3 was unlocked at 10 and rank 4 was unlocked at level 20

Comment: Actually, it's level 31 for the Pathfinder weapons (Deluxe Edition DLC).

Comment: This is only correct for blueprints that are unlocked with research points. Default blueprints unlock 1 level later (6, 11, 21, 31, etc).