# Question about armour and weapons

Tags: mass-effect-andromeda

I have noticed in the game there are certain blueprints that show up in development without me researching them like the avenger assault rifle, initiative armour the pathfinder armour, now does anyone know why is it dependant on how far you get in the campaign as I'm not that far or am I getting the blueprints and I just don't know I am

Answer (score 2):

All of the 'basic' armor and weapon blueprints are given to you whenever you hit the appropriate level, the same system for being allowed to research new blueprints, except it is +1 above that as noted by SGR.

Rank V blueprints unlock at level 31.

Ranks VI-X unlock every 10 levels beyond 31.

Also see [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/304295/at-which-player-level-are-new-gun-levels-unlocked/304299).

Comment: This is incorrect. Research blueprints unlock at those levels, but the blueprints for things like the M8 Avenger and Pathfinder armour unlock at those levels +1 (for example, Rank V M8 Avenger can be developed at Level 31)

Comment: @SGR I stand corrected, I'll edit that in